# Saving large amounts of dynamic user input

Tags: java, session, user-input, dynamic-data

I have a client application program that has 10+ classes each with 100+ components that need to be kept track of. When the program is run the user inputs numbers, selects items, toogles checkboxes, etc. I need to come up with a way to save all of the data input when the program is closed and have the capability of when the program is run again grab all the data from a previous time being run.

I have looked into Serialization but some of the things I need saved are not serializable so that didn't work. I have also looked into SingleFrameApplication and session storage but only in vain.

Writing to a file would cause the need for hours of tedious coding and would probably be inefficient. Does anyone have any ideas of how else I could tackle this hairy beast of a problem?

Update:

Doing what @home suggest I did the following:

```
public Main() throws FileNotFoundException {       
    initComponents();   
    //read the file 
    Read();
    //...
}

private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
    try {
        //write to the file, the program is closing
        Write();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void Read() throws FileNotFoundException {
    try{
        XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.xml")));
        //set the JTabbedPane to what is in the file
        tab = (JTabbedPane) decoder.readObject();
        decoder.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        //there was no test.xml file so create one
        XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.xml")));
        encoder.writeObject(null);
        encoder.close();
    }

}

private void Write() throws FileNotFoundException {
    XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.xml")));
    //clear all previous things in the file
    encoder.flush();
    //write the JTabbedPane into the file
    encoder.writeObject(tab);
    encoder.close();
}
```

After these changes all that pops up when I run the program is a blank JTabbedPane. Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: Um, you're talking about a fat (rich) client application or a web application?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to serialize an object compatible with JavaBeans specification, look at XML Encoder and Decoder: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html, http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html

EDIT: Tutorial here: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/persistence4/

Comment: Okay so i have a JTabbedPane that contains most of the classes used in the program. If i made the xmlencoder just write the JTabbedPane object would all of the components contained in it be written to the file as well?

Comment: I'd not write the `JTabbedPane` itself. You should separate your model from your GUI components. I'd create something like 'UserInputBean' containing all the attributes you need.